# Ambiguous tag created and added to older posts

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

A new tag [specialized](/questions/tagged/specialized) was created 20 hours ago and added to 3 older posts. The tag name itself is way too generic and the tag wiki is:

> Customizing generic code for specific cases

Does the community agree that [specialized](/questions/tagged/specialized) is a meta-tag for Stack Overflow and should be manually removed?

**Update:** Seems like `specialized` is a terminology specific to `scala`. A quick search reveals the following:

> One interesting feature that was added to Scala in version 2.8 is
>   specialization, using the @specialized annotation.
>
> Annotate type parameters on which code should be automatically
>   specialized. For example: class MyList[@specialized T] ...
>
> Type T can be specialized on a subset of the primitive types by
>   specifying a list of primitive types to specialize at:
>   class MyList[@specialized(Int, Double, Boolean) T] ..

I guess it is not a meta-tag but an incorrectly named tag, so it should not be removed. How about we rename it to **[specialized.scala]**?

Comment: I agree with you on the idea, but I notice the tag was added only to Scala questions. Maybe this is a technical term that has a specific meaning in Scala, and a better wiki and tag name would be in order instead of plain eliminating this? (Note that I am 100% clueless about Scala.)

Comment: Certainly, that is the exact reason why I didn't remove the tag and asked here. In any case, a rename is essential otherwise it will be a mess to keep the tag usage clean after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477675/why-are-so-few-things-specialized-in-scalas-standard-library) suggests it's referring to a specific piece of Scala terminology, so it's not a meta tag as such (my emphasis):

> ### Why are so few things @specialized in Scala's standard library?
>
> I've searched for the use of `@specialized` in the source code of the
>   standard library of Scala 2.8.1. It looks like only a handful of
>   traits and classes use this **annotation**: `Function0`, `Function1`,
>   `Function2`, `Tuple1`, `Tuple2`, `Product1`, `Product2`, `AbstractFunction0`,
>   `AbstractFunction1`, `AbstractFunction2`.

That said, I would say it wants a better name: perhaps [specialized-annotation](/questions/tagged/specialized-annotation), if that's indeed the kind of thing it is. And a better tag wiki.

Comment: This seems sane, obvious and well-explained.  I've retagged the four questions.  Who wants to do the tag wiki?